# How can I display my android screen on a DSUB or DVI port?

Tags: android, dvi, adapter

My videocard just borken and I have must be waiet 2 week for him.
But I have a idea.
I have a Sony xperia z2 with somany features like screen mirorr MHL, DLNA etc, and how about if I can somehow mirorring my screen in to my monitor?
Unfortunety my monitor only DSUB port supported, but I have DVI adabter so I can project out my screen also with this.
Is there any device with I can do this?
(Sorry my very bad english, I tryed write clean, I hope everybudy can understand it)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use your Android device as an external monitor in the way that you are describing. But if you have Remote Access enabled on your computer, you can remote into it using the Remote Desktop Protocol with your phone.

There are a number of applications on the Play Store that can do this, I would suggest the [Microsoft one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android&hl=en) though.

They also have a detailed article about how to get it to work [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473010.aspx).

Comment: I can't set any program if I not see the screen. I founded this what your comment for it: http://www.pcland.hu/delock_atalakito_mhl_male_to_vga_female__usb_micro-b_-65336

Comment: That cable will display your Android screen a monitor, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, but it works? What your opinion?

Comment: @HerbáriaBalance If you want to make your Android screen bigger, then it will work.